# an identity involving the floor function.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Assume that $x$ is a real number and that $m$ and $n$ are positive integers. $[x]$ denotes the greatest integer that is $\leq x$. Can the following identity be true? $$[mnx] = m([nx]+1).$$
I tried to use $$[mnx]=[x]+[x+{\frac{1}{mn}}]+\cdots +[x+{\frac{mn-1}{mn}}],$$ and $$m([nx]+1)=m[x]+m[x+{\frac{1}{n}}]+\cdots +m[x+{\frac{n-1}{n}}]+m.$$
I cannot seem to compare these two expressions! I have no reason to believe that this identity is true. It is an expression that came up in the course of my thinking about another problem. Any insights would be useful!

Comment: Try $x=0$ and any other values for $n$ and $m$.  By the way, the proper symbol for floor is $\lfloor x \rfloor$.  This allows $\lceil x \rceil$ for ceiling.  What do *you* use for ceiling?

Comment: I don't use the ceiling much! As I am trying to prove a theorem in diophantine approximation. Thanks for clearing up the notation though!

Answer (score 2):

Let $\ell=\lfloor mnx\rfloor$, so that $\ell\le mnx<\ell+1$, and let $k=\lfloor nx\rfloor$, so that $k\le nx<k+1$, and hence $mk\le mnx<m(k+1)$. Thus,

$$\lfloor mnx\rfloor=\ell\le mnx<m(k+1)=m(\lfloor nx\rfloor+1)\;,$$

so in fact $\lfloor mnx\rfloor<m(\lfloor nx\rfloor+1)$.

Answer (score 1):

A very useful tip when dealing with floor functions: remember the definition at all times!

Suppose $mnx = [mnx] + \alpha$. By definition $\alpha \in [0, 1)$. So $nx = \frac{[mnx]}m + \frac\alpha m$. Further suppose that $[mnx] = mk + r$, where $0\le r< m$. Then $nx = k + \frac{r + \alpha}{m}$. We would like to verify that $mk+r = m(k + \left[\frac{r + \alpha}{m}\right] + 1)$, which, upon taking $r \ne 0$, becomes false.